# Função quee acha o último nó da Lista e insere um novo nó no final da Lista

Tags: lista-encadeada

Complete a função abaixo que acha o último nó da Lista e insere um novo nó no final da Lista. Qual o problema
dessa função? Como melhorá-la?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sou novato em estrutura de dados, se alguém conseguir me dar uma luz, porque tá muito difícil entender a lógica sem a resolução.